# How to remove focus of edit text in list view after scrolling?

Tags: android

I have an edit text in my adapter view.when I am scrolling list view i am loosing the data entered in edit text, I am tried all the solutions given in this website .but not worked? How can I achieve this..

this is my focus changer listener..

```
private class OnFocusChange implements OnFocusChangeListener {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus) {
            ediTextWatcher = new EditTextWatcher((int) v.getTag(), "remark");
            ((EditText) v).addTextChangedListener(ediTextWatcher);
        } else {
            ((EditText) v).removeTextChangedListener(ediTextWatcher);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps u:

```
if (!hasFocus) {
                EditText et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.ur_editext);                  
                mylist.get(position).put("data", et.getText().toString().trim());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can achieve the expected output by using the below code .....

package mobile.sachien.com.myapplication_imageload;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListviewActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] arrText =
            new String[]{"Text1","Text2","Text3","Text4"
                    ,"Text5","Text6","Text7","Text8","Text9","Text10"
                    ,"Text11","Text12","Text13","Text14","Text15"
                    ,"Text16","Text17","Text18","Text19","Text20"
                    ,"Text21","Text22","Text23","Text24"};
    private String[] arrTemp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lyt_listview_activity);

        arrTemp = new String[arrText.length];

        MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
        listView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arrText != null && arrText.length != 0){
                return arrText.length;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arrText[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = ListviewActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lyt_listview_list, null);
                holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.editText1 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.ref = position;

            holder.textView1.setText(arrText[position]);
            holder.editText1.setText(arrTemp[position]);
            holder.editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                              int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    arrTemp[holder.ref] = arg0.toString();
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView textView1;
            EditText editText1;
            int ref;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: actually i solved it by using if (((ListView) parent).getSelectedItemPosition() == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
     parent.requestFocus();
     hidekeyboard(parent);